# Entity Framework 6 error: Cannot find the InsertFunctionMapping for EntityType 'EntityName' in the mapping file

Tags: entity-framework-6

EF noob here so bear with me if this is a stupid question.

**Some back-story setup**

I cannot, for the life of me, reliably update my EF model (Database First).

First, I could not implement my Delete operation and it turned out that I was missing my Primary Key.  Fair enough.  I added the key on the database and ran Update Model from Database.  This, of course, did nothing.  I hacked around for a few hours and finally got it working randomly.  During that time, I thought that maybe switching to a stored proc would do the trick (it didn't) so I removed it.

Once my delete functionality was working, **I added the Delete procedure back** to do some testing and eventually removed it again.  At this point I moved on to implementing my edit and create functionality.  *Deletion still worked after removing the procedure.*

**The issue**

Now, I receive the error message I posted in the title when trying to Create an record.  From what I've read, EF entities are "all or nothing" when it comes to using stored procedures.  If you implement Delete, **you have to** implement Insert and Update.  But, I've removed it so I shouldn't be required to implement these anymore.

Here's what I've done:

1. I've removed all `Stored Procedure Mapping`
2. I've removed the Delete stored procedure from the model (and any mention of it in the XML)
3. I've ran `Update Model from Database...`
4. I've used `Run Custom Tool` on both `Entity.Context.tt` and `Entity.tt` template files
5. I've completely deleted the entity from the .edmx file, cleaned the project, rebuilt the project and then ran `Update Model from Database...`
6. I've searched within the XML for **any** text related to `FunctionMapping`

What are the correct steps to keeping EF up to date so things like this do not happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the context was completely borked.  I deleted the entire thing and started from scratch with a new context and the small template customizations that we had added (additional constructors, entity collection name, etc.).

This fixed whatever was wrong with it.